# sql: group by bases on computed column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by

I have this data that shows consolidated report grouped by year. What I have used is a simple 
`GROUP BY YEAR(BookingDate)` clause and everything works fine. But what I want is the year to be financial year (`1 April` to `31 May`) and not the normal calender year, so how can I do this? The query is..

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), c.Duration) AS Duration, 
    COALESCE(c.totalbookings, 0) AS totalbookings
FROM
    (SELECT 
               YEAR(bookingdate) AS Duration, 
               COUNT(*) AS totalbookings 
           FROM 
               entbookings
            WHERE BranchId=@Branchid
           GROUP BY YEAR(bookingdate)
    ) AS c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
               Duration, 
               SUM(totalitems) 'bkdqty'
           FROM 
               [yrItemWISeTotalQty] (@BranchId) AS BkdQty
           GROUP BY Duration
    ) AS d 
ON c.Duration = d.Duration
```

The `yrItemWISeTotalQty` is defined as

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[yrItemWiseTotalQty]
(
@BrachId VARCHAR(MAX)
) 

RETURNS TABLE AS
    RETURN
SELECT 
    YEAR(EntBookings.BookingDate) AS Duration, 
    Sum(dbo.EntBookings.ItemCost) AS totalcost,
WHERE   EntBookings.BranchId = @BrachId
GROUP BY Year(EntBookings.BookingDate)
```

Again, I am using `GROUP BY Year()` that does the work great, but I need to modify it to take the fy i.e. (1 April to 31 March). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT 
    case when month(EntBookings.BookingDate) <4
         then YEAR(EntBookings.BookingDate)-1
         else YEAR(EntBookings.BookingDate) end  AS Duration, 
    Sum(dbo.EntBookings.ItemCost) AS totalcost
WHERE   EntBookings.BranchId = @BrachId
GROUP BY case when month(EntBookings.BookingDate) <4 
         then YEAR(EntBookings.BookingDate)-1 
         else YEAR(EntBookings.BookingDate) end as [year]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a SQL function
`getFinancialYear(Data[TimeStamp] )`
to return financial year number and use that to group by and.
I.e.

```
...
GROUP BY getFinancialYear(BookingDate)
...
```